# How to make a userfeed scroll on a new mysql input?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a userfeed for the homepage of my website that displays new information from users, for example: user x just did somthing.

This is what it looks like sofar: [Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlme9.png)

this is the code used on the page:

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '
            <div class="media testimonial-inner">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                                <img class="img-responsive img-square" src="images/bierportaal.jpg" height="66" width="66">
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <span><a href="' . $row["naam"] . '"target=main>' . $row["naam"] . '</a></span>
                                <span>' . $row["tekst_before"] . '</span><a href="' . $row["item"] . '"target=main>' . $row["item"] . '</a>  
                    <span>' . $row["tekst_after"] . '</span> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
      ';
        }
    } else {

    }
    $db_conx->close();
    ?>
```

My question is, How do I rotate trough the activities?
So that when someone does somthing (it will be inserted into the database)the records jump and the top one will display a new record and the bottom one wil move out of the screen/disapear.

An example of what i have in mind is on this website the activetyfeed:
[ratebeer website](http://www.ratebeer.com)

Kind regards,

Aerosteon

Comment: your question is a bit unclear i think. Could you specify what you mean, and especially, what you have tried and why it's not working?

Comment: I just have the data now i need to make it move, I havn't tried anything for the moving part yet because i have no clue where to start. But the idea is to loop torugh the data and show the lets say 10 most recent items from my database.

Comment: Yes. That would do the trick. Where is the problem?

Comment: In making it move by itself instead of refreshing the page. have u looked at the website i put in the post? thats the excact thing i want to happen.

Comment: Not sure if that is waht you are looking for: Retrieve your data ordered my date (or ID) descending, limited to the amount of records you want to show